# Каковы максимально и минимально допустмые линейные размеры объекта в сцене?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

Мне понадобилось создать условно бесконечную плоскость в сцене. Из этого возник ряд вопросов, не смог найти это в спецификации WebGL :

- каковы максимальные линейные размеры объекта в сцене, при значениях выше 10^7 плоскость уже начинает отображаться странно, при значениях выше 10^8 она исчезает;
- каковы минимальные размеры объекта в сцене;
- насколько далеко объект может располагатся от 0, равно ли это расстояние теоритическому максимальному линейному размеру объекта в сцене;
- почему при каких-то экстремальных значениях отрисовка элементов начинает давать сбои.

На сколько я понимаю, это также могут быть аппаратные ограничения + ограничения браузера,но опять же нигде не нашел этого.

Comment: [the_viewing_frustum](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_model_view_projection#the_viewing_frustum)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy каким образом максимальные размеры зависят от конуса обзора? Конус обзора это лишь текущая видимая область сцены.

Comment: Если вы поместите плоскость за `far plane` она не будет отражена.